# State sharing across trigger and evictor

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using the `GlobalWindow` with a custom `CountTrigger` (similar to the `CountTrigger` provided by `flink`).
I'm also using an evictor to remove some of the elements from the window. Is it possible to update the count when an element is evicted? For example: Can I access the `ReducingState` used by the `CountTrigger` from my `Evictor` class, so that the count always reflects the number of elements in the windows?

http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/State-sharing-across-trigger-and-evictor-td21328.html

Edit (more details): I want a count window, but with an added condition that the counts have to be within a time period. If they are in the allowed time-frame, I emit them, else I have to slide the window. How I meant to achieve this was using an Evictor to remove the older events. But I can't figure out how to update the count in the Trigger.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve? As far as I know you can't access Flink managed state from an evictor but maybe there is another to work around it.

Comment: @gcandal I want a count window, but with an added condition that the counts have to be within a time period. If they are in the allowed timeframe, I emit them, else I have to slide the window.
How I meant to achieve this was using an Evictor to remove the older events. But I can't figure out how to update the count in the Trigger.